# cocos2d start / stop running Scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scene

I'm trying to load one scene. This runs fine the first time, but when I try to reload again appears a white square where the animation is placed.

This is the code to start and stop the scene. What I'm missing?

thanks.

```
-(void)runScene:(OTAnimationCC2d *)animation
{
    scene = [CCScene node];

    [scene addChild:animation];

    if ([[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] isRunning])
    {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
    }
    else
    {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
    }

}
-(void)stopScene
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] stopAllActions];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:scene];

}
```

Comment: Need more info... how are these methods being called and why are you pushing the scene back onto itself at the end of stopScene.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `[self runScene]` at the end of `stopScene` rather than `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:scene]`? It sounds like you want the scene to reload fresh, which your `runScene` already does when it calls `replaceScene`.

Either way you should be creating a new scene node and using `replaceScene` (which is being done in `runScene` and is why I recommend just calling that).